# Разница между ssh -X и ssh -Y

Tags: x11, ssh, linux

Стало интересно, а в чем разница между этими опциями?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Разница в следующем:

- при использовании `ssh -X host` удаленная машина рассматривается как ненадежный клиент; поэтому при нарушении каких-либо правил безопасности, будет ошибка;
- при использовании `ssh -Y host` удаленная машина рассматривается как надежный клиент; поэтому при нарушении каких-либо правил безопасности ошибки не будет, а будут произведены запрашиваемые действия.

При этом оба варианта используются для перенаправления X11, то есть для работы с графическим клиентом через SSH.